# How to make google search in browser adjust to window size?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

I generally use my browser side by side with some application(s) so that I could make a google search while doing some work. But the problem is that the google search page doesn't adjust according to the browser window size.
For example, see the following image (Please note that the black patches in the image are just to hide the content):
[image]
In this image, I have four applications on my screen and at top right, I have Google Chrome where I made a Google search. What I need is that the search results should fit the browser window size, unlike as in the image shown, I have to scroll horizontally to see the results completely. Basically I want it to behave like text re-flows in a text editor according to size of the windows size.

My question is if there is any browser or browser extension that supports this functionality or is there some other application that allows search while adjusting to window size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mobile version of the search by changing your user agent. Extensions do exist that allow you to change the user agent just for a domain.

Alternatively, you can give Duckduckgo a shot which does not have this problem and is responsive by window width instead of by user agent.

[Here's](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/101635/why-is-the-google-search-results-page-not-responsive) some perspective regarding Google's Search UX

Answer (score 0):

You can open the browser’s dev tools, and set the screen size to an iPad for example. The downside is you would have to leave the devtools open, but you can minimize it. Perhaps a different search engine would be a good option.